# How to find a data from array and set this data in first index of array

Tags: javascript, sorting, ecmascript-6, jq

Here is my data

```
"Post_Comment": [
    {
        "comment": "nice",
        "user": {
            "username": "sahed"
        }
    },
    {
        "comment": "best",
        "user": {
            "username": "motalib"
        }
    },
    {
        "comment": "nice.",
        "user": {
            "username": "admin"
        }
    }
]
```

But I want to find an object through **username** and set this object in the first index into the array. I want to find this object whose user name is **motalib**.

Expected output:

```
const findCurrentUser = Post_Comment.findIndex(r=>r.user.username === username)
const SortedComment = Post_Comment.splice(findCurrentUser,1)
```

```
"Post_Comment": [
             {
                "comment": "best",
                "user": {
                    "username": "motalib"
                },
            },
            {
                "comment": "nice",
                "user": {
                    "username": "sahed"
                },
            },
            {
                "comment": "nice.",
                "user": {
                    "username": "admin"
                },
            }
        ]
```

Example:

```js
const Post_Comment = [
    {
        "comment": "nice",
        "user": {
            "username": "sahed"
        }
    },
    {
        "comment": "best",
        "user": {
            "username": "motalib"
        }
    },
    {
        "comment": "nice.",
        "user": {
            "username": "admin"
        }
    }
];

const findCurrentUser = Post_Comment.findIndex(r=>r.user.username === 'motalib')
const SortedComment = Post_Comment.splice(findCurrentUser,1)
console.log(SortedComment)
```

Comment: How is this question related to `jq`? Do you want to write a shell script?

Comment: @jabaa Yes of course it's related to jq(jQuery). Tag suggestion is here, jq is a sed-like tool for JSON data – you can use it to slice, filter, map, and transform structured data with the same ease that sed, awk, grep and friends let you play with text. View tag

Comment: jq is not jQuery. It's a command line tool. Can you elaborate the relationship? Do you call a command line tool from your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to swap them you can do:

```
const users = Post_Comment
const idx = users.findIndex(r=>r.user.username === username)
[users[0], users[idx]] = [users[idx], users[0]]
```

If you want to add it to the beginning while moving other elements indexes you can do:

```
const users = Post_Comment
const idx = users.findIndex(r=>r.user.username === username)
users.unshift(...users.splice(idx, 1))
```